# Help regarding an integral in about certain probability

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

In the following $V$ is an uniform variate in $(0,1)$ ,$T$ is another independent  random variable with CDF $t^{n-1} $and $u>1$ is a parameter.A friend sought help in an assignment in the calculation following two steps:
\begin{aligned}
P[V<u-1 , \quad & T<(u-1)(u-V)] &=\int_{V=0}^{u-1} \min \left(1,(u-1)^{n-1}(u-V)^{n-1}\right) d V \\
&=\int_{t=1}^u \min \left(1, t^{n-1}(u-1)^{n-1}\right) d t
\end{aligned}
I could not understand either of the two steps.I would be highly obliged for any help,mathematically or programmatically in Mathematica in this regard

Comment: I am sorry ,it meant T and not W

Comment: Your friend didn't give you all of the necessary information:  (1) the domain of positive support for $T$ is $(0,1]$, and (2) $n>1$.  And a bit more minor is that $u$ is better labeled as a "known constant" rather than a "parameter".

Comment: As currently described, your question while interesting doesn't seem to have anything to do with the software *Mathematica*.  Perhaps you meant to post this at https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I see that you also cross-posted this as math.stackexchange.com.  You should note in each forum that you've simultaneously asked this question elsewhere.  Otherwise, you would be wasting the time of folks in one forum if the answer or good comments are in the other forum.

Answer (score 2):

The second equality can be grounded by the change of the variable as follows.

```
Inactive[Integrate][Min[1, (u - 1)^(n - 1)*(u - V)^(n - 1)], {V, 0, u - 1}];
IntegrateChangeVariables[%, t, V == t - 1]
```

> `Inactive[Integrate][ Min[1, ((-1 + u) (1 - t + u))^(-1 + n)], {t, 1, u}]`

To ground the first equality, `W` should be defined.

Addition. After your edit the command of Mathematica

```
Probability[ V < u - 1 && T < (u - 1)*(u - V),
{V \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
 T \[Distributed]  ProbabilityDistribution[(n - 1)*t^(n - 2), {t, 0, 1}]}]
```

results in

> `Piecewise[{{1, u >= 2}, {(1 - (-1 + u)^n + n*(-1 - u + u^2))/ (n*(-1 + u)), Inequality[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, Less, u, Less,  2]}, {((-1 + u)^(-1 + n)*(-1 + u^n))/n,  Inequality[1, Less, u, LessEqual, (1 + Sqrt[5])/2]}}, 0]`

Comment: The command `Integrate[Min[1, ((-1 + u) (1 - t + u))^(-1 + n)], {t, 1, u}, 
 Assumptions -> u > 1 && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && n > 2, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]` returns the input, the code `u = 3/2; n = 3; Integrate[
 Min[1, ((-1 + u) (1 - t + u))^(-1 + n)], {t, 1, u}]` produces `19/96`, and `Piecewise[{{1, 
    u >= 2}, {(1 - (-1 + u)^n + n*(-1 - u + u^2))/(n*(-1 + u)), 
    Inequality[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2, Less, u, Less, 
     2]}, {((-1 + u)^(-1 + n)*(-1 + u^n))/n, 
    Inequality[1, Less, u, LessEqual, (1 + Sqrt[5])/2]}}, 
  0] /. {u -> 3/2, n -> 3}` gives `19/96`.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ has a Beta distribution with parameters $n-1$ and $1$.  The cdf is found with

```
Simplify[CDF[BetaDistribution[n - 1, 1], t] // FunctionExpand, Assumptions -> n > 1]
```

[image: CDF of T]

with pdf

```
pdfT = PDF[BetaDistribution[n - 1, 1], t] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: pdf of T]

To find the requested probability using the `Integrate` function consider

```
Integrate[pdfT*1, {v, 0, Max[0, Min[1, u - 1]]}, {t, 0, (u - 1) (u - v)},
  Assumptions -> u ∈ Reals]
```

[image: Requested probability]

This results in the same answer as given by @user64494.